# getting file name with regular expression php

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match

I'am trying to use regular expression to get just file name from URL for example:

```
$link = "http://localhost/website/index.php";

$pattern = '/.*?\.php';

preg_match($pattern, $link, $matches);
```

but it returns "`//localhost/website/index.php`" instead of "`index`".

Comment: you can get a file name in the file browser like total commander

Comment: please explain what do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your code even run? You haven't used any delimiters...

With `preg_match`, you could use a negated class instead, because `/` matches the first `/` then `.*?` will match all the characters up to `.php`... and if you want to get only `index`, it would be simplest to use a capture group like so:

```
$link = "http://localhost/website/index.php";
$pattern = '~([^/]+)\.php~';
preg_match($pattern, $link, $matches);
echo $matches[1];   # Get the captured group from the array $matches
```

[image]

Or you can simply use the [`basename`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function:

```
echo basename($link, ".php");
```

Comment: @AhmedDousa It's a delimiter. I could have used `|` instead, or `-` or  `#` or `@` etc. If I had used `/` as delimiter however, I would have had to use the pattern like this: `/([^\/]+)\.php/` (i.e. I would need to escape all the `/` in the pattern). I usually use `~` if my pattern has any `/`, so that I don't need to escape them, and this symbol is quite rare, so all the better to use.

Comment: @Jerry, I added an explanation with the help of an image. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be *much* better off using a function dedicated to the purpose, rather than a custom regular expression.

Since the example you provided is actually a URL, you could use the `parse_url` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

You should also look at the `pathinfo` (well done PHP on the naming consistency there!):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

You could then do something like this:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/path/file.php';
$url_info = parse_url($url);
$full_path = $url_info['path'];
$path_info = pathinfo($full_path);
$file_name = $path_info['filename'] . '.' . $path_info['extension'];

print $file_name; // outputs "file.php"
```

This might seem more verbose than using regular expressions, but it likely to be much faster and, more importantly, much more robust.